# How can I see if a polynomial is solvable by radicals or not?

Tags: galois-theory, solvable-groups

We consider
$$x^5 + 5x^4 + 10x^3 + 10x^2 + 5x - 2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$$
and
$$x^5 - x + 5 \in \mathbb{Q}[x].$$
I want to see if they are solvable by radicals or not.

I know that firstly I should determine the splitting field of our polynomials and the Galois group of it. However, I can't think of how to do this...

Could you help me, please? Thanks!!

Comment: The first one is $(x+1)^5 - 3$.

Comment: @DanielArreola So if $\zeta$ is a primitive fifth root of unity then the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[5]{3}, \zeta\right)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second polynomial

$$p(x):=x^5-x+5$$

**Theoretical side :** there are results on Galois groups of such monic polynomials with $3$ terms which can be found [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82775447.pdf). If we consider its Lemma 9, as $1+1<5$, $p(x)$ is irreducible. Moreover, the discriminant of $p$ (see below) is $1952869=239 \times 8171$ without square factors. Therefore, Theorem 6 of the same paper can be applied : the Galois group of $p$ is the symmetric group $S_5$.

**Practical side :** here is a Sagemath program :

> ```
> p=QQ['x'](x^5-x+5)
> d=p.discriminant();show(d);show(factor(d))
> gal=p.galois_group();
> n=gal.order();show(n)
> gal.is_isomorphic(SymmetricGroup(5))
> ```

giving the answers :

Discriminant : $d=1952869=239 \times 8171$

Galois group order : $n=120=5!$

With the confirmation that the boolean given by the fourth instruction is "True".

Comment: Intresting things also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Solvable_quintics) with a paragraph devoted to polynomials of the form : $X^5-X+q$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is really interesting to me, I love it! I was thinking about the Abel theorem too… It says that if $f(x) \in K[x]$ is an arbitrary separable irreducible polynomial of degree $n \geq 5$ and $E$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$ then $\text{Gal}(E|K) \cong S_n$. Do you think I could use it too?

Comment: But what knowledge do we have of this splitting field $E$ ?

Comment: Is it important? I mean, we know that $f(x)$ is solvable by radicals if and only if $\text{Gal}_K(f) = \text{Gal}(E|K)$ is solvable by radicals, right? If this Galois group is isomorphic to $S_5$…

Comment: Indeed. I am a little rusty, for I haven't done that much Galois theory these last years.

Comment: No worries!! I love your answer, and also I had no idea there was any program that did something like that. I mean, I literally just discovered SageMath and I am really impressed. Anyway, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Thanks for your thanks. It is very simple indeed to use sagemath (see my remark [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4826800/305862)). Besides, I have made a small modification : I ask the computation of the discriminant to Sage (instead of Wolfram Alpha)